# angular2 traceur not found

Tags: angular, systemjs

I import in angular2 some module and  have error. traceur not found. Example angular2-google-maps
system.config.js

```
var map = {
...
'angular2-google-maps/core': 'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/src/core',
...
};
var packages = {
  'angular2-google-maps/core': {
    main: 'core-module.ts', // or index.ts
    defaultExtension: 'ts'
  },
  ... 
};
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
```

error:
 http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 not found

how right way settings modules in angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview), You have to import the umd file to get it working properly. Importing the `TS` files will never work, because your browser doesn't want `typescript`, it wants `Javascript` ones.

```
var map = {
...
'angular2-google-maps/core': 'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js',
...
};
var packages = {
  ... //NOT CHANGED
};
```

Comment: if did not files core.umd.js. How generate It?

Comment: I download  version angular2-goggle-map [link]https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/tree/ee34fc0c82fe88be07d53b03008ab0e8ec385723 with polygone and don't have core.umd.js[/link]. How import this google map. Mybe will compile this module?

Comment: This is strange, why aren't you using npm?

Comment: I use npm, but i did know how install goolge maps in another branch

Comment: how use npm install 2.0.0-support branch for example?

Comment: you can't using npm, but if you really want to use a git branch (which is quite hard because its content can change at any moment) you should download it and then call `gulp build` in it, it should build the `umd.js` file

Comment: thanks for answer. I build new  version angular2-google-map but gulp don't created .umd.js file and I tried include js files in dist folder but i had not true result

Comment: I think your only options here is to wait for the changes you need to be published to npmjs, and install using `npm install angular2-google-map`